# Debugging Photon Server

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, photon

I am developing online game with Unity3D and PhotonServer on backend and I am using Visual Studio 2013 to debug my project.  When I start debug my project VS asks me to provide some Photon Server's sourcecode files (e.g. ApplicationBase.cs, PeerBase.cs). How to fix it? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe http://forum.exitgames.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=423 helps

Comment: ApplicationBase.cs, PeerBase.cs are not publicly available. Therefor you can't debug those files.

Comment: ApplicationBase.cs, PeerBase.cs are in file Photon.SocketServer.dll, this file doesn't have .pdb file, that why you can't debug it. Press F10 (Visual Studio) to jump over it